# Magento1.9 - I have a program with the shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9

In checkout page when a user tries to make a request.
When you are in the part of the form to select the shipping method, in this section you are stopped and cannot move forward.
Click on continue but it only shows the loading icon and does not continue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para deshabilitarlo y reparar checkout.haga lo siguiente.
Configuración> Configuración> Avanzado + Administrador> Seguridad> Deshabilitar "Habilitar validación de clave de formulario al finalizar la compra".
To disable it and repair checkout, do the following.
Settings> Settings> Advanced + Administrator> Security> Disable "Enable form key validation at the end of the purchase".